# How can I store state of something in a database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following problem with my Xamarin application.

I have a Quiz App, which I want to store information, when a quiz has been finished successfully by the user. It is somewhat like when you finish a lesson in Duolingo. I want to store information about that particular quiz in the database and use it to indicate that the quiz has been finished successfully, also paint the circle of the quiz in green or whatever color you may think of. [image: The image shows the quizzes whose state must be saved to the database when the quiz is finished].

Comment: add a "Completed" column with an INT (or bool or similar) type and use 1 to signify that it has been completed.   This is a basic db design question, it has nothing specific to do with Xamarin

Comment: Thanks, as I have no previous experience with SQL I couldn't even think of that, I thought of using SQLite, but I didn't know how to use it for my case. 
Thanks again, you forwarded me in the right direction.

Comment: Please adjust the tags on your question. This really is a database design question, as pointed out by @Jason

Comment: you can use settings plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin

Comment: @Anand that is a bad idea. The settings are not easily portable and hard to manage structured data in a simple key/value store.

Comment: Actually the thing is I managed to put the values for each button like.. "First", "Second" as strings, in a single table of the SQLite database. The thing is, I managed to insert INTO the database ,but I can't seem to find a way to READ from it.... it shows me the following when I try to read the two values [Database.IdState] (IdState is the string that I use from a customly written class to insert data into the database...) so when I try to read fro the database I can't really get the exact same value, but this. I tried parsing it to list and using the string.Join method, but same result.

Comment: When I try to read from the database I get the same result, or worse, errors. I tried reading from the SQLIte database with the SQLite class, then tried with the one from System.Data.SqlClient and finally with the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite one....getting different errors from all those tho. Anyways, hopefully somebody can help me fix that (I literally read everything I could find on the internet about that and still can't manage to fix that problem with the reading from the database).